# Check order of two elements in Java-8-Stream

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I want to check the order of two elements in a Java-8-Stream.
I have this Iterator-Solution:

```
public static boolean isBefore (A a1,
                                A a2,
                                Stream<A> as) {
    Iterator<A> it = as.iterator ();
    while (it.hasNext ()) {
        A a = it.next ();
        if (a == a1) {
            return true;
        } else if (a == a2) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException (
        a1 + " and + " a2 + " arent elements of the stream!");
}
```

Is there a solution without iterators in a more functional/non imperative style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be something like this

```
as.filter (a -> (a==a1) || (a==a2)).findFirst ()
```

And then check if the result is a1 or a2 or empty.
I'm sorry I don't give a full solution,  it's hard to do if from my smart phone

Comment: Actually I'm not even sure there's a first method,  but limit (1) could also do the job

Comment: `findFirst()` returns an `Optional` which will be empty if neither was found, i.e. is not `null`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the edit. I was away from my computer and couldn't check the API to verify the method names.